# Is it possible to have a 2-way binding to latitude and longitude with angular google maps?

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I'm using the following code to display a google maps on my angular app:

```
<agm-map id="map" [(latitude)]="lat" [zoom]="zoom" [(longitude)]="lng" [zoomControl]="false"
    [streetViewControl]="false">
  </agm-map>
<span>{{lat}} : {{lng}}</span>
```

On load, it works, I get the initial coordinates that I've in my controller.

If I update the `lat`or `lng` in my controller, it works, both the maps and the span are correctly updated.

But when I move the map with the mouse, lat and lng are not updated.

I need to change some collections of markers depending on the location.

Is this not supported or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not familar with agm-map but are you tried to use output event `boundsChange` or `centerChange`

Comment: It does not support two way binding as per the [docs and source code](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#source). There is no `Output` property called `latitudeChange`. You can try out the other events instead.

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I saw this, but, I'm a bit worried that if on each centerChange, I update the lat/lng, then the map will update its coordinates even it was maybe already somewhere else(drag&drop could be fast) :(

Comment: use it with subject and debounceTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [centerChange](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#centerChange) output event emitter to get latitude and langitude. As @AshotAleqsanyan mentioned in the comment you can use debounceTime operator to delay the emission of values.

**component.html**

```
<agm-map id="map" [(latitude)]="lat" [zoom]="zoom" [(longitude)]="lng" [zoomControl]="false" (centerChange)="centerChange($event)"
    [streetViewControl]="false">
  </agm-map>
 <span>{{lat}} : {{lng}}</span>
```

**component.ts**

imports

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators";
```

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  subject: Subject<LatLngLiteral> = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subject.pipe(debounceTime(300)).subscribe(details => {
      this.lat = details.lat;
      this.lng = details.lng;
    });
  }

  centerChange(code) {
    this.subject.next(code);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm just a bit worried: in my case; I've to update those two fields(lat and lng) with those values, so if I do this, agm-map will try to update according those position, I'm a bit affraid it will prevent the drag&drop to work properly(there is a lot of event coming when you drag and rop)

Comment: It will trigger centerChange event mulitple times, if you assing the lat lng value back to lat lng input

Comment: @J4N Please check the answer

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Nice! I just tested it, it works in almost all cases. I just noticed one issue: If you drag, wait a moment at the same place(without drop), then you cannot continue to drag. Not a big deal but still curious.

Comment: @J4N honestly I don’t know what it can be connected with. I am not familiar with atm-map. just can you check is it connected with delaying, Please can you remove .pipe(debounceTime(300)) and check it, sorry I can't test it on my side.

Comment: @J4N can it be bug from the module what do you think?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I think it is due to the module receiving coordinates from the "exterior" of the component and then it probably mess with its drag&drop mechanism. Anyway, it's not a blocking issue, I'm already quite happy with that! I didn't know about debounceTime, I can see a lot of usages, thank you very much!